Sphinx / read-the-docs stopped showing matplotlib plots from notebook documentation
I wonder if anyone could please help me with this issue:
I have a small library whose documentation is a mixture of .rst and jupyter notebook files. In the past, I just used nbsphinx to compile the notebooks, but recently, I switched computers and the matplotlib figures not longer show.
I opened an issue but I did not get a reply. If I run the command:
python -c "import sys; print('\n',sys.version); import ipympl; print('ipympl version:', ipympl.__version__)" && jupyter --version && jupyter nbextension list && jupyter labextension list

I get:
ipympl version: 0.9.3
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython : 8.23.0
ipykernel : 6.29.4
ipywidgets : 8.1.2
jupyter_client : 8.6.1
jupyter_core : 5.7.2
jupyter_server : 2.13.0
jupyterlab : 4.1.6
nbclient : 0.10.0
nbconvert : 7.16.3
nbformat : 5.10.4
notebook : 7.1.2
qtconsole : 5.5.1
traitlets : 5.14.2
Known nbextensions:
config dir: /home/vital/anaconda3/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
notebook section
jupyter-matplotlib/extension enabled
- Validating: OK
nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main enabled
- Validating: problems found:
- require? X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
jupyterlab-plotly/extension enabled
- Validating: OK
pydeck/extension enabled
- Validating: problems found:
- require? X pydeck/extension
jupyter-js-widgets/extension enabled
- Validating: OK
contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main enabled
- Validating: OK
tree section
nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main enabled
- Validating: problems found:
- require? X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
JupyterLab v4.1.6
/home/vital/PycharmProjects/lime/venv/share/jupyter/labextensions
jupyter-matplotlib v0.11.3 enabled OK
jupyterlab_pygments v0.3.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_pygments)
@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v5.0.10 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
@jupyter-notebook/lab-extension v7.1.2 enabled OK

Before I used the %matplotlib notebook magic command but with %matplotlib widget I have the same problem. In the the online compilation I cannot find any warnings either.
I wonder if anyone could please point me towards any diagnostic which could help identify this issue. In case it is related, the latex text is not displayed either.

Comment on your 'Before I used ...' statement that may help others: With ipympl, the documentation is very clear you use %matplotlib ipympl (or less explicitly, and therefore best to no longer be emphasized, as you note, %matplotlib widget). So %matplotlib notebook is only a thing for notebooks not running in Jupyter Notebook7+ or current JupyterLab. So with Jupyter Notebook 6.4 or lower or NbClassic you can continue to use %matplotlib notebook. ...

 For OP, I'd suggest you may want to update this section to suggest %matplotlib ipympl instead of what you have because it helps users associate this with needing to install ipympl.

Thank you very much @Wayne for the correction. I agree ipympl is the best option to run my library on a notebook.  I will explain that better on the documentation.
